# What is the best file format for saving a dictionary of dataframes with Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have 365 dataframes, each associated with a date in a year. Because I want to readily extract them by specifying the dates. I use a dictionary to map each date to its dataframe. What is the best format for saving this dictionary, `D`?

```
D = {"2019-01-01":df1, "2019-01-02":df2, ... , "2019-12-31":df365}
```

By "best" I mean the following (**descending priority**):

- **Feasibility**: not every format fits due to serialization problem
- **Accessability**: ideally I can upload the dataset to Github/GoogleDrive and load it with a link
- **Space Efficiency**: a file as small as possible
- **Compatibility**: ideally I can load the dataset in either Python or in R

So I guess the options include `.json`, `.npz`/`.npy`, and `.p`?

Comment: It depends of how you want to work with this dictionnary. If you work only with python, pickle is fine for that.

Comment: @Renaud Thanks! I have heard about `pickle` but never used it because its official webpage says it's not secure haha https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Comment: "Only unpickle data you trust". :)

Comment: @Renaud haha ok THX! ^_^

Comment: @Renaud One more thing, can I upload the .p file to Github or Google Drive and unpickle it using URL? Would be convenient if I work from different terminal and don't have to worry about datasets.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the whole thing into a single dictionary. Pandas Dataframes have a `.to_dict()` method.
Just convert each dataframe into a dict and replace. Dump the whole thing into a json. This would be more memory efficient that python objects like pickle.

It goes without saving that you will also have to write some trivial extra code to convert it all back.

Answer (score 0):

Do 365 dataframes have the same columns? You can flatten the whole dataset into one dataframe, then query by date. Will use more space, but close to what you could have achived in a tabular database.